# difference between these conditional situations

Tags: conditionals

what is the difference between these conditional sentences? I mean in which situations we use any of them?

- If you look at the map, we wont be lost.
- If you looked at the map, we wouldn't be lost.
- If you had looked at the map, we wouldn't have been lost.
- If you had looked at the map, we wouldn't be lost.

Answer (score 2):

1. If you look at the map, we won't be lost.

We are currently lost.  If you look at the map, we will stop being lost.

2. If you looked at the map, we wouldn't be lost.

Non-idiomatic. Would probably be interpreted by most people the same way as sentence 4

3. If you had looked at the map, we wouldn't have been lost.

We were, at some point in the past, lost. This could have been avoided by you looking at the map.

4. If you had looked at the map, we wouldn't be lost.

We are currently lost. This could have been avoided by you looking at the map.